# Laravel 9 Breeze api Authenticate with different user types

Tags: laravel, laravel-9, laravel-api, laravel-breeze

How can I check the user type in LoginRequest of laravel breeze?

I am implementing Laravel breeze with next.js for my backend. The logic is that the admin login to the dashboard using the next.js frontend and the users login to the system from an app in Flutter. I have seperate routes for each ends.

/user/login for app in flutter
/login for nextjs

Both routes point to the same controller AuthenticatedSessionController::class. In the LoginRequest, is there a way to authenticate only users or only admins? I have the type column in Users table to distinguish usertypes.

Comment: When you do `$user = \Auth::user();` then check user type for user object.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. On the LoginRequest file, search the User model with the email and store it in a variable. Then check if the user type is admin else throw a validation exception.

Implemented authenticate function:

```
public function authenticate()
{
    $this->ensureIsNotRateLimited();

    $login_type = filter_var($this->input('user'), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)
        ? 'email'
        : 'username';

    $this->merge([
        $login_type => $this->input('user')
    ]);
    //Added this
    $user = User::where($login_type, $this->input('user'))->first();
    if ($user->type == 'admin') {
        if (!Auth::attempt($this->only($login_type, 'password'), $this->boolean('remember'))) {
            RateLimiter::hit($this->throttleKey());

            throw ValidationException::withMessages([
                'email' => __('auth.failed'),
            ]);
        }
    } else {
        RateLimiter::hit($this->throttleKey());
        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            'email' => __('auth.failed'),
        ]);
    }

    RateLimiter::clear($this->throttleKey());
}
```